# JTree: Missing link between TreeNode and TreePath

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I have a problem which was also described [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4143848).

I have the `invertExpand` method in `MyTree` class which works like this:

```
public void invertExpand(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    TreePath path = new TreePath(node.getPath()); // no better way to get TreePath from TreeNode :(
    if (!isExpanded(path)) {
        expandPath(path);
    } else {
        collapsePath(path);
    }
}
```

But the problem is `isExpanded()` method uses the `HashMap` to store the expanded paths. It seems that `isExpanded()` never returns `true` for newly created `TreePath`. (But they are expanded really)

**Does any way to fix that issue?**

Comment: well, next time show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem (instead of leaving that task to the answerer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Expand/collapse works on non-leaf nodes, so be sure that the node in question is not a leaf:

```
public void invertExpand(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    if (node.isLeaf()) 
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getParent();
    TreePath path = new TreePath(node.getPath()); // no better way to get TreePath from TreeNode :(
    if (isExpanded(path)) {
        collapsePath(path);
    } else {
        expandPath(path);
    }
}
```

**Edit** (as per OP's comment)

The real reason for the misbehaviour was an incorrectly implemented hasCode in a custom node which confused the Map (where the expanded paths are stored).

Comment: well, then your node implementation is incorrect - leafs can't be expanded, so get what you asked for (from the tree ;-) BTW: now it's _really_ time for an sscce, without there's no way to answer your question ...

Comment: hmm @kleopatra please write in answer that `isExpanded()`, `expandPath()` and `collapsePath()` use the `HashMap` so I need to check the overrides of the `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: hmmm, curious: _why_ did you override equals, it's a bit unusual?

Comment: My node is quite complex, it's equality should not being determined with ALL of fields.